# Delete multiple line in a text file but it is deleting only last line

Tags: python-3.x

```py
def delet_line(exp_res):
    filename = "C:\\Users\\beher\\Desktop\\my.txt"
    exp_res_sl = exp_res.splitlines()
    #print('file name is ',filename)
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    for expres_line in exp_res_sl:
        print(expres_line)
        with open(filename, "w") as f:
            for line in lines:
                if line.strip("\n") != expres_line:
                    f.write(line)

delet_line("Mohan\nmohan")
```

Here i am trying to delete the a multiline string passing as argument but it deletes only the last line of the passing argument pls help| thanks in advance.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code in the question.

Comment: Why would you give it a formatted string, then split it again instead of just passing a list? Also, indent your code. If this is how you ran it, then it will not work due to an Indentation Error.

Comment: You should loop over `lines` first and check if `line` in lines is in the list `exp_res_sl`. If it is not add to the output file. When using `with` you do not need to close the file handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like so:

```
def delete_line(skip_lines):
    filename="C:\\Users\\beher\\Desktop\\my.txt"
    with open(filename, "rt") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    with open(filename, "wt") as f:
        for line in lines:
            if line.strip('\n') not in skip_lines:
                f.write(line)

delete_line(['Mohan', 'mohan'])
```